# Auto - New Tor Circuit For This Site or New Identity

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, circuit, identity-change

Building a JS chat for local network. Users are based on IP addresses. I want to open a URL in Tor Browser with a new circuit or a new identity after a set of defined seconds automatically.

Is there a command I can run where I open tor with the url as a parameter? Then I can put it in a batch file and make it run after every few minutes.

Is there a way I can simulate a shortcut like Ctrl+Shift+L through the browser's console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. Go to your Tor Browser folder, open **cmd** in the *Browser* folder and type this

`firefox.exe "http://google.com"`

you can put this in batch, but kill the process before you start the new browser. 
You can also change the homepage of the browser when it starts if you always want to open a single url and just `firefox.exe` in your cmd window.

**Update**

`for /l %%x in (1,1,100) do (
start browser/firefox.exe "http://google.com"
timeout /t 100
taskkill /im firefox.exe /f
)`

save as file.bat and run